# Regex: Split the string at \n

Tags: regex

I try to get just the title of the following line:

```
1. Title\nThis is the text line
```

The result should be

```
<span>1. Title</span>This is the text line
```

My problem is to split the string at the `\n`.

```
#^\d+\.((?:\d+(\.)*)*)\h+.\n(?:.)+$#s
```

https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/3 or https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/4

Comment: Sorry, but my problem is shown in my example link. There is no line break, but just the characters `\n` in that string

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/6

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that optionally? I mean if there is no `\n` at all, the complete line should be used. (If there is a `\n` only the string until there should be used - like it is be done by your regex)

Comment: if there is no `\n` then how you identify which one is title and which one is the content.

Comment: In that case there is just the title without content: https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below regex.

```
^(\d+\.(?:\d+\.*)*\h+.*?)(?:\\n|$)
```

`(?:\\n|$)` at the last helps you to match upto the backslash `n` or upto the end of the line.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tD9bP6/9)